# How can I save time series (x, y) coordinate in prometheus to be shown in grafana with XY Chart?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In the positioning system, a (x,y) position is generated every second. Can the (x,y) coordinates be saved to the Prometheus and displayed using the XY Chart in Grafana? Please show me the code.

I think it's impossible because no metric can express two value at the same time, but it's possible with MySQL, can anyone find a way?

I want to display the historical points (x, y) over a period of time in XY Chart, like scatter plots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two independent metrics for your data. For the sake of this answer let's call them `metricX` and `metricY`.

To showcase them at Grafana's XY Chart you'll need to do the following:

1. Add panel, select type "XY Chart",
2. add query `metricX` as first query,
3. under query expand **Options**. Select **Table** in Format dropdown,
4. repeat 2-3 for query `metricY`,
5. switch to tab Transform,
6. add transformation **Join by field**

- Mode: **INNER**,
- Field: **Time**.

You will get something like this:
[image]