# Collecting labels and query results data from multiple metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am learning and experimenting with Prometheus metrics and Grafana dashboards. The information is coming from a Kubernetes cluster.

I am struggling with figuring out how to collect together information about pods, that is coming from multiple metrics. I believe the metrics involved are all related in some way. They are all in the `kube_pod...` "family".

### Background

I've used a technique like the following that works for a simple metric to metric case:

```
(metric_A) + on(<common_label>) group_left(<metric_B_label>, ...) (0 * metric_B)
```

This allows me to associate a label from the right side that is absent from the left side via a common label. There is no arithmetic involved, so the add and multiply really do nothing. The `on` (or `ignoring`) operator apparently requires a binary operator between the left and right sides. This seems really clunky, but it does work and I know of no other way to achieve this.

Here's a concrete example:

```
(kube_pod_status_phase != 0) + on (pod) group_left (node) (0 * kube_pod_info)
```

The `kube_pod_status_phase` provides the `phase` (and, of course, `pod`) of each pod (Running, Failed, etc.), but does not have the node information. The `kube_pod_info` has the `node` label and a matching `pod` label. Using the query above provides a collection of pods, their current phase and which node they're associated with.

### Problem

My current task is to collect the following information:

| Node | Pod | Status | Created | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node_1 | pod_A_1 | Running | mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss | {x}d{y}h |
| node_1 | pod_B_1 | Running | mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss | {x}d{y}h |
| node_2 | pod_C_1 | Pending | mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss | {x}d{y}h |
| node_3 | pod_A_2 | Running | mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss | {x}d{y}h |
| node_3 | pod_B_2 | Failed | mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss | {x}d{y}h |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

My plan is to get the status (phase) from the `kube_pod_status_phase` metric, the created date/time and the age from the `kube_pod_start_time` metric and include the corresponding node from the `kube_pod_info` metric. The age is calculated as `time() - kube_pod_start_time`.

Another detail that complicates this is that the `phase` and `node` are *labels* in their respective metrics, while the created date/time and age are the "result" of running the queries (i.e. they are *not* labels). This has been causing me problems in several attempts.

I tried seeing if I could somehow chain together queries, but in addition to being incredibly ugly and complicated, I couldn't get the result values (created date and age) to be included in the results that I managed to get to work.

If anyone knows how this could be done, I would very much appreciate knowing about it.

Comment: Assuming pod label is unique within your dataset, you can do two queries: 1. returning first four columns of your table, and 2. returning pod and age. Make types of your queries table (options under query), and then join them using transformation join by field, and use field pod.

Comment: Not following on how to make types of the queries. I couldn't find what you're referring to. Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: I meant [format](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/query-editor/#format) of the query, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016395/how-can-i-save-time-series-x-y-coordinate-in-prometheus-to-be-shown-in-grafan/76021781#76021781) somewhat similar to what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a method that does what I need. Thanks to comments from https://stackoverflow.com/users/21363224/markalex that got me going on the thought track.

I ended up creating 3 queries:

```
(kube_pod_status_phase{namespace=~"runner.*"} != 0) + on (pod) group_left (node) (0 * kube_pod_info)

time() - kube_pod_start_time{namespace=~"runner.*"}

kube_pod_start_time{namespace=~"runner.*"}
```

Then joining them together with a "Join by field" transform on the `pod` label. Finally, used an "Organize fields" transform to hide the columns I don't care about as well as some re-ordering.

Comment: You could probably skip "joining" using promql, and extract `kube_pod_info` as a separate fourth query.